# Constructor vs. preStart: when to use which?

Tags: akka

In Akka you can initialize the actor's state within the constructor. Furthermore, as part of the actor's lifecycle, the `preStart` method can be overridden to initialize the actor's state and will be called:

- when the actor is first started, before it starts processing its first message
- when the actor is restarted, *unless* `postRestart` is overridden to not call it

The two ways (constructor and `preStart`) seem to cover overlapping phases of the actor's startup phase, with the slight difference that the constructor is *guaranteed* to be called upon restart, whereas `preStart` can be skipped, provided that you override `postRestart`.

Are there recognized or documented best practices or patterns regarding which one to use in which case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the documentation on [initialization via constructor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#initialization-via-constructor):

> Using the constructor for initialization has various benefits. First of all, it makes it possible to use `val` fields to store any state that does not change during the life of the actor instance, making the implementation of the actor more robust. The constructor is invoked when an actor instance is created calling `actorOf` and also on restart, therefore the internals of the actor can always assume that proper initialization happened.

From the documentation on [initialization via preStart](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#initialization-via-prestart):

> The method `preStart()` of an actor is only called once directly during the initialization of the first instance, that is, at creation of its `ActorRef`. In the case of restarts, `preStart()` is called from `postRestart()`, therefore if not overridden, `preStart()` is called on every restart. However, by overriding `postRestart()` one can disable this behavior, and ensure that there is only one call to `preStart()`.
>
> One useful usage of this pattern is to disable creation of new `ActorRefs` for children during restarts. This can be achieved by overriding `preRestart()`.

If you want initialization to occur **every time an actor is instantiated** (which includes restarts: on a restart, a new instance of the underlying actor is created), use initialization via constructor. The example scenario for this is the use of invariant state whenever an actor is created.

If you want initialization to occur **only when the first instance of an actor is created**, use initialization via `preStart` and override `postRestart` to not call `preStart`. The example use case for this is the preservation of child actors across restarts (by default, `preRestart` stops an actor's children, which is why the documentation mentions overriding `preRestart` for this example use case).

Comment: Ha, I haven't gone deep enough in the documentation before asking. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your good answer:-) But I've got one question remaining. Suppose I use the method which does not stop the children in order to not trigger the generation of new ActorRefs. How will the actor know about the children's ActorRefs after a restart? A restarted actor is created from scratch without any state of the old stopped instance. How can it figure out the list of the children's ActorRefs?